# (C) Trying to read a .txt file into a 2d array (and failing, mind you!)

Tags: c, windows, memory, memory-management, multidimensional-array

I've worked quite a bit with PHP and some with C++ but am brand new to C, as you can tell by my jumbled mess of code. Basically, I'm looking to read the contents of a .txt file (a grid, in this case to make a game for my friends and I) into a 2d array, process the file's contents, and output the processed content into a separate .txt file.

```
void grab_input(char *infile, int *rows, int *cols, char *buffer);
void send_output(char *outfile, int rows, int cols, char buffer);
int process_input(char *buffer);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int rows;
    int cols;
    int i;
    char **buffer;
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s filename\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    buffer = (char**)malloc((rows + 2) * sizeof(char *));
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        buffer[i] = (char *)malloc(cols*sizeof(char));
    grab_input(argv[1], &rows, &cols, &buffer);
    process_input(&buffer);
    send_output(argv[2], rows, cols, *buffer);
    printf("\n%s\n", argv[2]);
    printf("%d\n", cols);

    return 0;
}

void grab_input(char *infile, int *rows, int *cols, char *buffer)
{
    FILE *input;
    input = fopen(infile, "r");
    if (input != 0)
        printf("The file exists.\n");
    else
        printf("No file.\n");
    fscanf(input, "%d %d", rows, cols);
    printf("Unprocessed grid:");
    while (fgets(buffer, (*rows+2) * (*cols+2) * sizeof(char)+1, input) != NULL)  {

        printf("%s", buffer);
    }
    fclose(input);
    printf("\nRows: %d\nColumns: %d\n", *rows, *cols);
}
```

For which I receive several console errors and a "Debug Error... Stack around the variable cols was corrupted." I've done a lot of reading on various sites about dynamic memory allocation, but I'm obviously not quite grasping how to actually put it into practice and make a dynamically-allocated 2D array from a file. If you could help me, it'd be greatly appreciated.

[Here's a picture of my console window.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1y9lC.png)

[And here's one of the contents of my input.txt file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/003rd.png)

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Please do not post text as images. And doubly not so as external links. Copy both the console output and the input file contents as text into the question. Otherwise others cannot copy the text for commenting or for replicating your issue.

Comment: Passing what you read to the first argument of `printf()` is **an security risk**. What if something like `%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s` is read? Use `printf("%s", buffer);` or `fputs(buffer, stdout);`.

Comment: `buffer = (char*) malloc((rows+2) * (cols+2) * sizeof(char));`. That is not the right way to allocate memory for a 2D array. Do a search, there are plenty of existing questions that address that very issue. Also, your code just has too many basic errors. Surely the compiler would have spat out warnings and you should not ignore those. For example, `grab_input` is defined with a last parameter as `char *` yet you call it with a `char ***`. Worse than that you are allocating memory for `buffer` **after** you have already attempted to use it in `fgets`. `fgets` does not allocate memory for you.

Comment: @kaylum Third parameter is `int*` and it is not wrong. What is passed as the forth parameter of `grab_input()` is `char***`, not `char**`.

Comment: Turning on compiler warnings would be a good start.  You're passing `&buffer`, which has type `char ***` to `grab_input`, which expects a `char *`.  Your compiler should warn about this.  This can't possibly do what you want.

Comment: @MikeCAT I can't count. I meant the fourth parameter. Corrected.

Comment: are we expected to guess as to which header files your program has `#include`d?   Are we expected to guess the prototypes for the functions you have written, called, but not posted?

Comment: never access beyond `argv[0]` without first checking `argc` to assure the expected command line parameters were actually entered?   If the expected number of command line parameters were not entered, then the code 'should' output to stderr, a 'usage' message, similar to : `fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s [parm1] [parm2] ... \n", argv[0] );`

Comment: when the call to `fopen()` fails, not only output a message (suggest using `perror()` not `printf()` ) but also exit the program.   Since the call to open the file failed, must not every access that file.  Best move is to call `exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); immediately after calling `perror()`

Comment: BTW:  `fopen()` returns a pointer (NULL when it fails) not an integer, so this line: `if (input != 0)` would be better written as: `if (input != NULL)`.  (note: implicit conversion might handle this bit of sloppy coding).  Also, to ease finding keypunch errors, like using `=`  instead of `==` it is better to place the literal on the left side of the comparison.  Then a keypunch error will be caught by the compiler rather than you having to spend hours and hours searching for the missing `=`

Comment: the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the C standard as 1, and (for the parameter to `malloc()` just clutters the code).  At other places where that expression is used, suggest just using 1 rather than that expression.

Comment: in C, when calling `malloc()` do not cast the returned value.  the type of the returned value is `void*` so can be assigned to any pointer.  casting just clutters the code, making understanding, debugging, maintenance much more difficult.

Comment: @kaylum I'm sorry, I should have realized the inconvenience that using images instead of copy/pasting could cause beforehand. My apologies. I guess I just don't understand how I can get the dimensions of the array (rowsxcols) out of the file while still allocating enough memory before using grab_input(). I updated my code in the OP to illustrate how confused I am.

I made a few updates, though I know I have a long way to go, still. Obviously, the updates aren't running due to memory issues. Thank you all so far.

Comment: the function: grap_input()` is reading data into 'buffer[]' but buffer is an uninitialized pointer.  so the data can end up anywhere in memory.  This is undefined behaviour and can (probably will) lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: @MikeCAT Thank you for pointing out that blatant security flaw. Hopefully I've addressed it suitably, now.

Comment: strongly suggest: reading only one line at a time from the input file, especially as the call to `fgets()` will stop inputting at the end of the first line. (a line is terminated via a newline sequence)

Comment: @user3629249 I apologize for not including my prototypes. I just include stdio.h and stdlib.h.
Also, thank you for pointing out my poor error handling. I will try to address it. I will also remove sizeof(char) and replace it with 1.

Comment: @user3629249 `0` is defined to be null pointer constant, so compareing pointer with `0` is not bad. I think using `NULL` is better for readability.

Comment: per that image of the input file, the file has 10 lines, not 8 and has 10 characters per line, not 9  So the row/column counts do not match the contents of the input file.

Comment: @MikeCAT,  NULL is not `void *(0)` on all architectures, so the assumption you expressed will work `most` but not `all` of the time.

Comment: @user3629249 N1256 6.3.2.3 Pointers "3 An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type
void *, is called a null pointer constant. 55) If a null pointer constant is converted to a
pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a null pointer, is guaranteed to compare unequal
to a pointer to any object or function."

Comment: Suggest have a function to read the first line of the input file, to obtain the number of rows and number of columns.  Then perform the call to malloc(), then (if malloc() successful) read the rest of the input file, row by row.

Comment: @MikeCAT, true enough when working with an OS (and not one of those 'special' architectures where NULL is not `void *(0)`).  However, the standard seems to be not taking into account when working with a bare metal machine, where some function, etc can be at address 0

Comment: this is an extract from the C operator precedence chart: `* & + -` where that line is from right to left, so the addition will be performed before the dereference.   Suggest instead of writing expressions like: `(*rows+2)`  to write: `((*rows)+2)`

Comment: this second parameter to the call to fgets(): `(*rows+2) * (*cols+2) * sizeof(char)+1`  will always write to the same location in buffer.  Is that what you want?

Comment: for various reasons, this line: `buffer = (char*) malloc((rows+2) * (cols+2) * sizeof(char));;`   should be written as: `buffer = malloc((rows+2) * (cols+2));`   Notice no cast, no multiplying by 1, no trailing extra semicolon.    Notice this is expected to allocate enough memory for the whole file, so why is only the first row being filled in the second call to `fgets()` in the function: `grap_input()`

Comment: @user3629249 No, it definitely isn't what I want. I'd like to be able to access each character in buffer individually with process_input().

Answer (score 0):

applying all the comments and cleaning up the logic and performing appropriate error checking results in the following.

The following cleanly compiles.

The following is not tested.

```
#include <stdio.h>  // fgets(), fopen(), fclose(), 
                    // sscanf(), fprintf(), printf()
#include <stdlib.h> // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE
#include <string.h> // memset()

void grab_sizeInfo( FILE *input, size_t *pRow, size_t *pCols );
void grab_input( FILE* fp_in, size_t rows, size_t cols, char **buffer);
void send_output(char *outfile, size_t rows, size_t cols, char **buffer);
void process_input(size_t rows, size_t columns, char **buffer);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    size_t rows = 0;
    size_t cols = 0;
    char **buffer = NULL;

    if (argc != 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s InputFilename OutputFilename\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    FILE *fp_in = NULL;
    if( NULL == (fp_in = fopen( argv[1], "r") ) )
    { // then fopen failed
        perror( "fopen for input file failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    grab_sizeInfo( fp_in, &rows, &cols );
    printf("\nRows: %lu\nColumns: %lu\n", rows, cols);

    rows+=2;  // adjust for actual size
    cols+=2;  // adjust for actual size
    cols+=1;  // +1 to allow for NUL terminator byte

    if( NULL == ( buffer = malloc(rows * sizeof(char *)) ) )
    { // then malloc failed
        perror( "malloc for array of pointers to rows failed");
        fclose( fp_in );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, malloc for array of pointers to rows successful

    // prep array of pointers, to make cleanup easy
    memset( buffer, '\0', rows * sizeof(char *) );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
    {
        if( NULL == (buffer[i] = malloc(cols) ) ) 
        { // malloc failed
            perror( "malloc for row failed" );
            // cleanup
            for( size_t j=0; j < rows; j++ )
            {
                free( buffer[j] );
            }
            free( buffer );
            fclose( fp_in );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, malloc for array of char in row successful

    } // end for each row

    grab_input( fp_in, rows, cols, buffer);
    fclose( fp_in );

    process_input(rows, cols, buffer);
    send_output(argv[2], rows, cols, buffer);

    printf("\n%s\n", argv[2]);
    printf("%lu\n", cols);

    return 0;
} // end function: main


void grab_sizeInfo( FILE *fp, size_t *pRow, size_t *pCols )
{
    char firstLine[20] = {'\0'};

    if( fgets( firstLine, sizeof firstLine, fp ) )
    { // successful read
        if( 2 != sscanf( firstLine, "%lu %lu", pRow, pCols) )
        { // then sscanf failed
            perror( "sscanf for rows and columns failed" );
            fclose( fp );
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
} // end function: grab_sizeInfo


void grab_input(FILE *fp, size_t rows, size_t cols, char **buffer)
{
    size_t rowNum = 0;
    while ( rowNum < rows && fgets( buffer[rowNum], (int)cols, fp ) )
    {
        printf("%s", buffer[rowNum]);
        rowNum++;
    }

    if( rowNum != rows )
    { // then failed to read complete file
        fprintf( stderr, "number of rows read: %lu Not equal Number expected rows: %lu\n", rowNum, rows );
        for( size_t i=0; i<rows; i++ )
        {
            free( buffer[i] );
        }
        free( buffer );
        fclose( fp );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
} // end function: grab_input
```